# Binding Single Item of a Collection

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm just learning the basic concepts of WPF and XAML coming from a C++ background, so some of it is a bit alien to me. I am using Expression Blend to help me get to grips with XAML.

I am making a basic app that displays records in a simple XML data source:

```
<photos>
  <photo>
    <image>Assets\Item01.png</image>
    <description>Strawberry</description>
  </photo>
  <photo>
    <image>Assets\Item02.png</image>
    <description>Orange</description>
  </photo>
  <photo>
    <image>Assets\Item03.png</image>
    <description>Pineapple</description>
  </photo>
  ...
</photos>
```

I have bound this data 'photoDataSource' to a grid and stuck some textboxes and image fields that display the first record. In XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource photoDataSource}}" Margin="0,0,0,1" Background="#FF1D1D1D">
    <Image Height="104" Width="104" Source="{Binding XPath=/photos/photo/image}" Margin="8,62,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox Height="23" Margin="8,8,6,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding XPath=/photos/photo/description}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox Height="23" Margin="8,35,6,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding XPath=/photos/photo/image}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Content="Next Product" Margin="213,97,297,0" Height="44" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

This displays two textboxes containing "Strawberry" and "Assets\Item01.png" respectively, along with the image and a Button Containing the text "Next Product". As you can see I have bound the collection "photoDataSource" to the parent Grid. When run it displays the first item in the collection.

How can I trigger the button to display the next item in the collection (and loop) at runtime?

I am not intending to do this with any code-behind as I am not changing any of the data itself, just which item is displayed. But perhaps I am going about this in the wrong way?

Ideally after this example I will want to remove the button completely and change records automatically after a storyboard animation has completed (using the trigger `'StoryboardCompletedTrigger'`).

Answer (score 1):

Quite right not wanting to use code behind. However I would recommend implementing a ViewModel against your Window to get what you want achieved.

In your view model you should have an ObservableCollection of your Photo object and another property to specify a single Photo being called SelectedPhoto as shown below:

```
public ObservableCollection<Photo> MyPhotos {
  get { return _photos; }
  set { _photos = value;
     if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Photos"));
  }
}

public Photo SelectedPhoto {
  get { return _photo; }
  set { _photo = value; 
     if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedPhoto"));
  }
}
```

Then use XmlSerialization to load your Xml into the ObservableCollection. Then create your buttons to move next and previous to bind to an ICommand (also in your ViewModel) to cycle up or down the MyPhotos collection setting SelectedPhoto each time.

Then you can bind and Image in your Xaml as follows.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource myViewModel}, Path=SelectedPhoto.Image}"/>
```

I hope this makes some sense for you and has been of some help.